# Kafka Consumer overwrites offsets of uncommitted messages

Tags: apache-kafka

Overview: I have a lambda setup with Kafka Consumer that polls messages from a Kafka cluster and indexes them to an Elasticsearch domain. The lambda is invoked every one minute which mean the client id of the Kafka Consumer changes but the Kafka group ID always remains the same. One key thing to note is that the consumer has auto-commit disable and that we're manually committing the offsets once the messages have been successfully indexed. In the case of unsuccessful indexing, our code just catches the error and logs it and does not commit those messages.

However, I've noticed that when the indexing fails, while the consumer does not commit the unindexed messages, it doesn't see those messages on subsequent polls either. Any messages published after the unindexed messages occupy the offset of the uncommitted messages.

To recreate this scenario, I ran a small test and saved the logs: 
`h`
https://pastebin.com/6aDzbvD4

From the logs, you can see that one record of size 415kb was polled at 16:06 and failed getting indexed to ES. On subsequent polls after 16:06, the uncommitted messages are nowhere to be seen. At 16:11, I published another message of size 3kb to the Kafka which was successfully polled by the consumer albeit at the same offset as the previous uncommitted message. This new message was indexed and committed successfully.

I'm new to Kafka and trying to understand why this could happen. I've also the config value of auto.offset.reset to "earliest" so the consumer should be able to see the earliest uncommitted messages. I'd appreciate any help regarding this!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a plain Consumer rather than Kafka Connect?

Comment: `auto.offset.reset` only applies when a `group.id` has not been initialized, and has no corellation for un-committed data.